# Laravel 5.6 Session takes newly created user after registration

Tags: php, laravel, registration

In my application I made use of the php artisan make:auth command to provide some early on user login & registration scaffolding.

It has come to my attention that everytime I create a new user whilst being logged in as i.e. UserX, my user changes after submitting the registration to the newly created user.

**Example below:**

- BEFORE REGISTRATION

Logged in as UserX

- AFTER REGISTRATION

Logged in as UserZ (newly registered user)

**=======**

I am wondering how I can make it so that when I create a new user through registration, the system retains the user that was logged in instead of taking on the newly registered user.

Below is the register controller:

**=======**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to login the user after its registration?

Comment: This seems like an odd "problem" to try and solve. How ofter are your users going to have an account when registering? Wouldn't it make more sense to just prevent access to `/register` if you're logged in? Also, if I register for an account on a site, I'd want it to A) automatically log me in or B) provide some feedback, like "Account created, please login."

Comment: @TimLewis It's based on a user creating a new user through the registration method provided by php artisan make:auth.

Comment: Ah, that's a different issue. If you need a way for a User to create a new User, that should be a different (or slightly adjusted) method; not the core `register` function.

Comment: Yeah I usually did it through making entire seperate create methods and all but I moreso was keen onto checking if there were methods available within the scaffolding provided. Guess I'll have to do with the good ol' UsersController and then craft a method for creating a user by a user in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to provide users the ability to add new users you should do so through a UsersController.

Now your new controller won't take on the behaviour of registration.  This would also make logic in your application clearer since you are not registering a user, you are creating a new one.

To expand a little, the RegisterController executes the following code when you register a user (through use Auth\RegisteredUsers register method).

```
        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

So in essence you must follow the approach I mention above unless you remove "use RegisteredUsers;" from the RegisterController which would not generally be recommended.  Using your separate controller / behaviour allows you to create additional logic such as checking for user type (e.g. Admin User) before allowing to create a user etc. etc.

Comment: Cheers mate. Guess I got a little too much bright minded when I thought it could have an easy fix, since I kinda didin't wanted to put in the hassle of creating extra logic for creating a new user whilst the registration part from make:auth already does that.

But likewise as you mentioned, it's a core Laravel thing so at the same time not good to tamper with or alter at all except for some wildcards such as where to redirect to after registration is complete.

I'll in the end thus make a new controller and attach routing to the logic it would contain.

Comment: You're welcome.  Nothing at all wrong with the approach from a design perspective in that you were looking at reusing existing components.